# Which circuit breaker is for the doorbell?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, doorbell

I am trying to install a wired Simplisafe doorbell. I tested with a voltmeter but maybe it doesn’t detect anything because the voltage is low?

Any way to be safer if I can’t find this transformer?

[image]

[image]

Trying to install a doorbell :)

Comment: A transformer is almost the same as a phone charger you plug in.  Doorbells are low voltage ~12 volts, so can be worked on with the power on.  Or just turn off the main breaker.

Answer (score 4):

That transformer may be connected to one of those breakers, but we have no way of knowing from what you've shown us.

Doorbells are typically powered by 24 volt transformers. The transformer may be inside or alongside the panel, or elsewhere. It looks like this:

[image]

<sub>[source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09PYKZYSM)</sub>

Either investigate the wiring for it or use the trial-and-error method.

All that said, you usually don't need to turn off a breaker to work on a doorbell since they're low voltage. Just don't stick the wires on your tongue. Also don't let the wires touch for any length of time or things can get warm. Brief contact isn't a problem.